# How do I convert a Hex color to and RGB color using T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

How do I convert a Hex color to and RGB color using T-SQL

Comment: Can you give a quick example of what you need in terms of source and result formats?

Comment: Users will input the Hex color and in the sproc, I want to save the RGB values to the table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/4803/so3087921

```
DECLARE @temp AS TABLE (hex char(6))

INSERT  INTO @temp
VALUES  ('3333CC') -- Should convert to Red: 51 Green: 51 Blue: 204

DECLARE @table AS varchar(16)
SET @table = '0123456789abcdef' -- Assuming case-insensitive collation!

SELECT  hex
       ,16 * (CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(hex, 1, 1), @table) - 1) + (CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(hex, 2, 1), @table) - 1) AS R
       ,16 * (CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(hex, 3, 1), @table) - 1) + (CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(hex, 4, 1), @table) - 1) AS G
       ,16 * (CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(hex, 5, 1), @table) - 1) + (CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(hex, 6, 1), @table) - 1) AS B
FROM    @temp
```

There's a generic function at https://dpatrickcaldwell.blogspot.com/2009/05/converting-hexadecimal-or-binary-to.html

I generally avoid scalar functions if at all possible, since it is possible to lure yourself into thinking that it's OK to call a scalar UDF for 5 million rows without any penalty over the inline expression.

You can also use an inline table-valued UDF:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_HexToRGB (@hex char(6))
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
    (
     SELECT 16 * (CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@hex, 1, 1), '0123456789abcdef') - 1) + (CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@hex, 2, 1),
                                                                                         '0123456789abcdef') - 1) AS R
           ,16 * (CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@hex, 3, 1), '0123456789abcdef') - 1) + (CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@hex, 4, 1),
                                                                                         '0123456789abcdef') - 1) AS G
           ,16 * (CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@hex, 5, 1), '0123456789abcdef') - 1) + (CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@hex, 6, 1),
                                                                                         '0123456789abcdef') - 1) AS B
    )
GO

DECLARE @temp AS TABLE (hex char(6)) 

INSERT  INTO @temp 
VALUES  ('3333CC') -- Should convert to Red: 51 Green: 51 Blue: 204 

SELECT  hex 
       ,R 
       ,G 
       ,B 
FROM    @temp
OUTER APPLY dbo.udf_HexToRGB(hex)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a table valued function I just wrote up. It takes the hex color value as a `char(6)` value and returns a table with `R`, `G`, and `B` columns. If you aren't on SQL server, it should be easy to adapt to your database.

```
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Josh Thompson
-- Create date: 2010-06-21
-- Description: Convert hex color to RGB
-- =============================================
CREATE FUNCTION [fn_hex_to_rgb](
    @hex char(6)
    )
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN (
    SELECT
        (
            (
                CASE LOWER(SUBSTRING(@hex, 1, 1))
                    WHEN 'a'
                        THEN 10
                    WHEN 'b'
                        THEN 11
                    WHEN 'c'
                        THEN 12
                    WHEN 'd'
                        THEN 13
                    WHEN 'e'
                        THEN 14
                    WHEN 'f'
                        THEN 15
                        ELSE CAST(SUBSTRING(@hex, 1, 1) AS int)
                    END
                *
                16
                )
            +
            (
                CASE LOWER(SUBSTRING(@hex, 2, 1))
                    WHEN 'a'
                        THEN 10
                    WHEN 'b'
                        THEN 11
                    WHEN 'c'
                        THEN 12
                    WHEN 'd'
                        THEN 13
                    WHEN 'e'
                        THEN 14
                    WHEN 'f'
                        THEN 15
                        ELSE CAST(SUBSTRING(@hex, 2, 1) AS int)
                    END
                )
            ) AS R,
        (
            (
                CASE LOWER(SUBSTRING(@hex, 3, 1))
                    WHEN 'a'
                        THEN 10
                    WHEN 'b'
                        THEN 11
                    WHEN 'c'
                        THEN 12
                    WHEN 'd'
                        THEN 13
                    WHEN 'e'
                        THEN 14
                    WHEN 'f'
                        THEN 15
                        ELSE CAST(SUBSTRING(@hex, 3, 1) AS int)
                    END
                *
                16
                )
            +
            (
                CASE LOWER(SUBSTRING(@hex, 4, 1))
                    WHEN 'a'
                        THEN 10
                    WHEN 'b'
                        THEN 11
                    WHEN 'c'
                        THEN 12
                    WHEN 'd'
                        THEN 13
                    WHEN 'e'
                        THEN 14
                    WHEN 'f'
                        THEN 15
                        ELSE CAST(SUBSTRING(@hex, 4, 1) AS int)
                    END
                )
            ) AS G,
        (
            (
                CASE LOWER(SUBSTRING(@hex, 5, 1))
                    WHEN 'a'
                        THEN 10
                    WHEN 'b'
                        THEN 11
                    WHEN 'c'
                        THEN 12
                    WHEN 'd'
                        THEN 13
                    WHEN 'e'
                        THEN 14
                    WHEN 'f'
                        THEN 15
                        ELSE CAST(SUBSTRING(@hex, 5, 1) AS int)
                    END
                *
                16
                )
            +
            (
                CASE LOWER(SUBSTRING(@hex, 6, 1))
                    WHEN 'a'
                        THEN 10
                    WHEN 'b'
                        THEN 11
                    WHEN 'c'
                        THEN 12
                    WHEN 'd'
                        THEN 13
                    WHEN 'e'
                        THEN 14
                    WHEN 'f'
                        THEN 15
                        ELSE CAST(SUBSTRING(@hex, 6, 1) AS int)
                    END
                )
            ) AS B
    )
GO
```

Comment: Whoops. I guess I should refresh the page first before answering a question. I think Cade's `CHARINDEX` solution is more clever and succinct, but I wonder which is faster.