# How to output RGB value from color represented as integer?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In `SQL Server 2012`, how would you convert a color represented by an `int` (stored as 0xBBGGRR) to a string of the format `R=123, G=234, B=12`? We will ignore the alpha part.

E.g. Given an integer of value `0xff223344`, you would get `R=68, G=51, B=34`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087921/how-do-i-convert-a-hex-color-to-and-rgb-color-using-t-sql

Comment: Actually I agree that it looks like a duplicate.  The "put the answer in a string" condition in this question is trivial.  However, since all the answers to this question are much more succinct and clean than all the answers to the other one... what is the best option?  Do we vote to close this one and copy the answers across?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use bitwise and (&) operator:

```
declare @i int
set @i=0xff223344

select 
  'R=' +   cast(@i & 0xFF as varchar(3)) +
  ', G=' + cast((@i & 0xFF00) / 0x100 as varchar(3)) +
  ', B=' + cast((@i & 0xFF0000) / 0x10000 as varchar(3))
```

Comment: Brilliant! Now, which one of the provided solutions is the most efficient one?

Comment: I chose bitwise AND and division because they were the cleanest code, rather than for speed.  It is how I would have done it in my Assembly coding days.  Nevertheless pure arithmetic operations are faster than string manipulation in practically any programming language.

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @i int
Set @i=0xff223344
select 
  'R=' + Cast(Cast(SubString(CAST(@i as BINARY(4)),4,1) as int) as Varchar(3))
+ ', G=' + Cast(Cast(SubString(CAST(@i as BINARY(4)),3,1) as int) as Varchar(3))
+ ', B=' + Cast(Cast(SubString(CAST(@i as BINARY(4)),2,1) as int) as Varchar(3))
```

Comment: Thanks! So which one of the provided solutions is the most efficient one?

Comment: The solution of @perfectionist seems to be faster. 
Loop 10000000 times division 29 sec vs. binary 33 sec

Answer (score 1):

What about such a solution?

```
declare @i int = 0x223344

select 'R=' + cast (@i % 256 as varchar)
    + ', G=' + cast (@i / 256 % 256 as varchar)
    + ', B=' + cast (@i / 65536 % 256 as varchar)
```

Or if you have an `ff` for alpha channel:

```
declare @i int = 0xff443322

if @i < 0
    set @i = @i % cast(0x1000000 as int) - cast(0xff000000 as int)

select 'R=' + cast (@i % 256 as varchar)
    + ', G=' + cast (@i / 256 % 256 as varchar)
    + ', B=' + cast (@i / 65536 % 256 as varchar)
```

Comment: Why not just use bitwise-AND? `SET @i = (@i & 0x00ffffff)`

Comment: Agree. That would be better.